# Tuning performance on SELECT statement from a medium-large table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, optimization

I've got a table with 45 columns and 600,000 rows. I need to tune up a SELECT statement from this table, which for now lasts about 41 seconds. I need to return all the columns and i don't use *. This table has no keys, constraints or indexes. It also has no unique value which could be used as a primary key. The data types of all columns are pretty much optimized so I guess that's not the issue.

Any tips or best practises?

Here's my execution plan with table scan tooltip.
   http://i59.tinypic.com/10xhe6g.jpg

Comment: It would help to add the actual query, don't you think?

Comment: Hm, number of rows – 605352, row size – 1212 B... So, are you asking why returning 700 MB of data takes 41 seconds and how to improve the speed?

Comment: @ypercube not really. As I mentioned - it is a simple SELECT statement with list of all columns. What would it change?

Comment: So, if it is really a `SELECT <all_columns> FROM tablename;` and the query returns all the 600K rows and all 45 columns, what tips do you expect to get?

Comment: We could, generally, advise you to start tuning your underlying system, based on [what waits](http://www.brentozar.com/responder/triage-wait-stats-in-sql-server/) happen during that query. But, like @ypercube is asking, would you change/tune the query or upgrade the CPU/RAM/disk/network?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a predicate in this query?
If so and cardinality of that column is high, you can create an index to get better performance.
But first figure out, how frequently this query will execute. If it executes once or couple of times a day you may not need to look at this one.